# Ajax call with basic authentication works on desktop butnot on device browser

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a weird issue.. I am trying to call a REST URL which is secured with basic authentication over https but for some reason the call doesn't go through when I perform it from a mobile device (iPhone/iPad). When I remove the basic authentication from the service the call goes through with authentication it just times out.

When I try to debug it on my desktop it works fine .. does anybody have any idea why this wouldn't work?

My call looks like this:

```
    var values = this.getLoginForm().getValues();
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : '/some/relative/url/',
        method : 'GET',
        username: values.username,
        password: values.password,


        success: function(response){
            loggedIn = true;


            Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Logged In');
        },


        failure : function(response) {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Error', response.responseText);
        }
    });
```

I tried with relative URL and with absolute and there seems to be no difference.

I am using Sencha Touch 2.3.1.

Comment: Does it return success or failure on mobile browser? what do you get when logging `response.responseText` on success?

Comment: The responseText is empty. It basically doesn't "reach" the server so it doesn't even come to the point of authenticating. Or the request doesn't contain enough info to do a basic authentication from a mobile browser.